LSTM financial model predict always the same value
I have the following issue: with my economic data and sentiment data, I want to predict the close price.
Particularly I want to take the first five data days in order to predict the close price of the sixth day.
First of all, as economic data I have the open, high, low and close prices; as sentiment data I have the mean of the polarity score aggregated by day of the headlines published for each ticker.
First of all I studied the correlation matrix. As I saw that there was a huge correlation between open, high, min and close prices so I decided to retain only the close price in my features data to be used in my model.
I have 50 tickers in my dataframe, so in order to create the sequence data for my model I defined the following functions:
def create_sequences(data, seq_length, feature_cols, target_col):
    features = feature_cols.copy()
    features.remove('ticker')
    ticker_list = []
    X = []
    y = []

    for ticker in data["ticker"].unique():
            ticker_data = data[data["ticker"] == ticker].reset_index(drop=True)
            ticker_data = ticker_data.drop('ticker', axis=1)
            for i in range(seq_length, len(ticker_data)):
                X.append(ticker_data.loc[i - seq_length: i - 1, features].values)
                y.append(ticker_data.loc[i, target_col])
                ticker_list.append(ticker)
        return ticker_list, np.asarray(X), np.asarray(y)

Sequence length is of 5 because I want the first 5 days in order to predict the sixth and the close price is a feature both in the X vector of the feature and in y vector of the labels. The features in x vector are: ["day","month","year","weekday","ticker","ticker_emb","title_count","volume","close"], the feature in y vector is ["close"].
Then I have definire the following functions to scale and create the dataset:
def define_scalers_per_ticker(dataframe_train):
    price_column = "close"
    scaler = {}

    for ticker in dataframe_train["ticker"].unique():
        ticker_data = dataframe_train[dataframe_train["ticker"] == ticker]

        scaler[ticker] = {}

        price_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
        price_scaler.fit(ticker_data[[price_column]])
        scaler[ticker][price_column] = price_scaler

        volume_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
        volume_scaler.fit(ticker_data[["volume"]])
        scaler[ticker]["volume"] = volume_scaler

    return scaler

def scale_ticker_data(scaler, dataframe):
    scaled_dataframe = dataframe.copy()

    numeric_columns = ["close", "volume"]
    scaled_dataframe[numeric_columns] = scaled_dataframe[numeric_columns].astype("float32")

    for ticker in dataframe["ticker"].unique():
        ticker_mask = dataframe["ticker"] == ticker

        for column in numeric_columns:
            scaled_values = scaler[ticker][column].transform(
                scaled_dataframe.loc[ticker_mask, [column]]
            )
            scaled_dataframe.loc[ticker_mask, [column]] = scaled_values


    return scaled_dataframe

def scale_dataframe(train_dataframe: pd.DataFrame, test_dataframe: pd.DataFrame):
    scaler = define_scalers_per_ticker(train_dataframe)

    df_train_trs = scale_ticker_data(scaler, train_dataframe)
    df_test_trs = scale_ticker_data(scaler, test_dataframe)

    return scaler, df_train_trs, df_test_trs

I definire the following dataset model and lstm model:
class TemporalDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, tickers, sequence_data, labels):
        self.data = sequence_data
        self.tickers = tickers
        self.labels = labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx)->Dict:
        ticker = self.tickers[idx]
        data = torch.tensor(self.data[idx], dtype=torch.float32)
        labels = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.float32)
        sample = {'ticker': ticker, 'data': data, 'labels': labels}
        return sample

class BaseLstmVar(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_lstm_layers, lstm_dropout,  dropout, output_size):
        super(BaseLstmVar, self).__init__()
        self.name = "BaseLSTMVar"
        self.lstm =nn.LSTM(
            input_size=input_size,
            hidden_size=hidden_size,
            num_layers=num_lstm_layers,
            batch_first=True,
            bidirectional=True,
            dropout=lstm_dropout if num_lstm_layers > 1 else 0
        )

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2*hidden_size, 50)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, output_size)
        self.leaky_relu = nn.LeakyReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        lstm_out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x)
        target = torch.mean(lstm_out, dim=1)

        out = self.fc1(target)

        out = self.leaky_relu(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)

        out = self.fc2(out)

        return out

Finally the train loop was defined as:
ticker_list_train, x_train, y_train = create_sequences(
    df_train_model, sequence_length, feature, 'close', True
)
ticker_list_test, x_test, y_test = create_sequences(
    df_test_model, sequence_length, feature, 'close', True
)

train_dataset = TemporalDataset(
    ticker_list_train, x_train, y_train
)
test_dataset = TemporalDataset(
    ticker_list_test, x_test, y_test
)

batch_size = 32

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)


net = BaseLstmVar(
    input_dim, hidden_lstm_size, lstm_num_layers, lstm_drp, dropout_rate, output_size
)

print(net)

epochs = 2
learning_rate = 1e-3
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.AdamW(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
device = detect_device()

train_logger = instantiate_logger(f"{model}_{net.name}_train_logger_pkl")

net = net.to(device)

# training
losses = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    net.train()
    epoch_loss = 0

    train_logger.info(
        f"Starting epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}"
    )

    for idx_batch, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        batch_x, batch_y = batch['data'].to(device), batch['labels'].to(device)
        outputs = net(batch_x)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_y.reshape(-1, 1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        loss_rnd = round(loss.item(), 4)
        epoch_loss += loss_rnd
        train_logger.info(
            f"Batch [{idx_batch + 1}/{len(train_dataloader)}], \t Loss: {loss_rnd: .4f}"
        )

    avg_epoch = epoch_loss / len(train_dataloader)
    losses.append(avg_epoch)
    train_logger.info(
        f"Avg epoch loss in {epoch + 1} epoch: {avg_epoch:.4f}"
    )

If I ask the model to predict on a batch, the issue is that I have always the same prediction. For examples, the real values are 25, 43, 52, but the predictions are always 63, for instance.
batch = next(iter(test_dataloader))
tickers, data, labels = batch['ticker'], batch['data'].to(device), batch['labels'].to(device)

output_test = net(data).detach().cpu().numpy()
output_real = labels.cpu().numpy()

unsc_out_test = []
unsc_out_real = []
for idx, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    unsc_out_test.append(scaler[ticker]['close'].inverse_transform(output_test[idx].reshape(-1, 1)).item())
    unsc_out_real.append(scaler[ticker]['close'].inverse_transform(output_real[idx].reshape(-1, 1)).item())

Where I'm doing the wrong thing? I do not know why my model is predicting the wrong values. I tried changing also the numbers of the epochs or the loss function with the HuberLoss, but the results do not change.
What I'm doing in a bad way?
Thank you for your time and your patience. I will be very grateful for any suggestion you'll want to provide.
